# Configuration for creating multiple instances of hazelcast in a single JVM

Tags: java, spring, hazelcast

I need to create two instances of hazelcast in a single tomcat server. I've integrated hazelcast with spring. Below are the configuration files.

hazelcast.properties

```
#First instance properties
hz.instance.name = mi
hz.group.name = mi
hz.group.password = password
hz.management.center.enabled = true
hz.management.center.url = http://localhost:8085/mancenter
hz.network.port = 5701
hz.network.port.auto.increment = true
hz.tcp.ip.enabled = false
hz.members = 127.0.0.1
hz.multicast = true
hz.multicast.group = 224.2.2.3
hz.multicast.port= 54327
hz.multicast.timetolive=32
hz.multicast.timeout.seconds=2

#Second instance properties
hz.instance.nameOne = miOne
hz.group.name = mi
hz.group.password = password
hz.management.center.enabled = true
hz.management.center.url = http://localhost:8085/mancenter
hz.network.port = 5701
hz.network.port.auto.increment = true
hz.tcp.ip.enabled = false
hz.members = 127.0.0.1
hz.multicast = true
hz.multicast.group = 224.2.2.3
hz.multicast.port= 54327
hz.multicast.timetolive=32
hz.multicast.timeout.seconds=2
```

hazelcast.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:hz="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
              http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring/hazelcast-spring.xsd">

    <hz:hazelcast id="instance">
        <hz:config>
            <hz:instance-name>${hz.instance.name}</hz:instance-name>
            <hz:group name="${hz.group.name}" password="${hz.group.password}" />
            <hz:management-center enabled="${hz.management.center.enabled}"
                url="${hz.management.center.url}" />
            <hz:network port="${hz.network.port}" port-auto-increment="${hz.network.port.auto.increment}">
                <hz:join>
                    <hz:multicast enabled="${hz.multicast}" />
                    <hz:tcp-ip enabled="${hz.tcp.ip.enabled}">
                        <hz:members>${hz.members}</hz:members>
                    </hz:tcp-ip>
                </hz:join>
            </hz:network>
        </hz:config>
    </hz:hazelcast>

    <hz:hazelcast id="instanceOne">
        <hz:config>
            <hz:instance-name>${hz.instance.nameOne}</hz:instance-name>
            <hz:group name="${hz.group.name}" password="${hz.group.password}" />
            <hz:management-center enabled="${hz.management.center.enabled}"
                url="${hz.management.center.url}" />
            <hz:network port="${hz.network.port}" port-auto-increment="${hz.network.port.auto.increment}">
                <hz:join>
                    <hz:multicast enabled="${hz.multicast}" />
                    <hz:tcp-ip enabled="${hz.tcp.ip.enabled}">
                        <hz:members>${hz.members}</hz:members>
                    </hz:tcp-ip>
                </hz:join>
            </hz:network>
        </hz:config>
    </hz:hazelcast>

    <hz:map id="map" instance-ref="instance" name="Map" />

</beans>
```

In hazelcast.xml if you can see I've registered two instances of hazelcast 
`instance` & `instanceOne`. `instanceOne` is almost the copy config. of `instance` If I remove `instanceOne` the second member/instance doesn't start. Say I have to create `n` instances of hazelcast in a single JVM. Do I have register the instance `n` times in `hazelcast.xml` or is there any better way to configure the beans?.

Comment: What you have is not a hazelcast.xml but a spring configuration!

Comment: Didn't I say in the beginning I've integrated hazelcast with spring.

Comment: Can you post the code part on how you are getting instance from Bean factory?

Comment: I hope the two instances are running on different machines as only one application is allowed to bind to a port when address is same i.e. `hz.members = 127.0.0.1` and `hz.network.port = 5701` would not allow second instance to come up.

Can you can change the port of second instance to **5702** and then give it a go ?